# ошибка при создании кнопки kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

после сборки программы, ничего не запускается и вылетает ошибка:

> kivy.uix.widget.WidgetException: Cannot add <kivy.uix.button.Button object at 0x000001535ACB4DD8>, it already has a parent <kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout object at 0x000001535ACA9A58>

вот код:

```
class ThirdScreen(Screen):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    output_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    button1_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

    output_lbl = Label(text=' ')
    self.output_lbl = output_lbl

    button_output = Button(text='Вывести анекдот')
    button_output.on_press = self.joke_output

    button_back = Button(text='Назад')
    button_back.on_press = self.back_slide

    output_layout.add_widget(self.output_lbl)
    add_widgets(button1_layout, button_output, button_back)

    add_widgets(main_layout,output_layout,button_output)

    self.add_widget(main_layout)
```

в другом классе структура кода идентичная, но при этом ничего не ломается